# events that fire all at once in Jquery without queue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to jquery.

The idea is to create two divs that when clicked on it, the clicked div will increase the size whereas the other decreases. These two divs will have an link when clicked, that div will flip independantly and not affecting the other div.

I am having two divs (say div1 and div2) which flip independently on clicking a link inside it. On clicking the div(say div1 here), I maximize it by adding a class maximize which I have defined in the css. and minimize the other class. I am able to achieve all.. but the events are happening one by one. which looks really wierd. I am posting the code below.

```
$('.recharge-panel').click(function (e) {
    $(".search-panel .flipper").hide();
    $('.recharge-panel').removeClass('minimized');
    $('.recharge-panel').addClass('maximized');
    $('.search-panel').addClass('minimized');
    $('.search-panel').removeClass('flip');
    $(".recharge-panel .flipper").show();
});
$('.search-panel').click(function (e) {
            $(".recharge-panel .flipper").hide();
            $('.search-panel').removeClass('minimized');
            $('.search-panel').addClass('maximized');
            $('.recharge-panel').addClass('minimized');
            $('.recharge-panel').removeClass('flip');
            $(".search-panel .flipper").show();
});
```

and the html goes like this

```
<div id="home-content-container4">  
<div id="div-box-container">
<div id="recharge-panel" class="contact homepanel recharge-panel">
    <div id="rechargefy" class="front">
        <p>This is the front side</p>
        <a class="flipper flipBack" href="#">Flip</a>
    </div>
    <div id="rechargefy" class="back">
        <p>This is the back side</p>
        <a class="flipper flipFront" href="#">Flip</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="contact homepanel search-panel second-panel">
    <div id="planSearch" class="front">
        <p>This is the front side</p>
        <a class="flipper flipBack" href="#">Flip</a>
    </div>
    <div id="planSearch" class="back">
        <p>This is the back side</p>
        <a class="flipper flipFront" href="#">Flip</a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

The css is as follows..

```
.maximized {
width: 500px;
height: 400px;
-o-transition: 0.5s;
-ms-transition: 0.5s;
-moz-transition: 0.5s;
-webkit-transition: 0.5s;
transition: 0.5s;}

.minimized {
width: 300px;
height: 200px;
-o-transition: 0.5s;
-ms-transition: 0.5s;
-moz-transition: 0.5s;
-webkit-transition: 0.5s;
transition: 0.5s;}

#div-box-container{
position: relative;
height: 600px;
width: 1024px;
-o-transition: 0.5s;
-ms-transition: 0.5s;
-moz-transition: 0.5s;
-webkit-transition: 0.5s;
transition: 0.5s;}

.homepanel {
float: left;
width: 400px;
height: 300px;
font-size: .8em;
margin-left: 10px;
-o-transition: 0.5s;
-ms-transition: 0.5s;
-moz-transition: 0.5s;
-webkit-transition: 0.5s;
transition: 0.5s;           
-webkit-perspective: 600px;
-moz-perspective: 600px;
font-family: "Lato","Lucida Grande","Lucida Sans Unicode","Trebuchet MS",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
```

}
I know I have screwed up.. if anyone can help me out in this, it will be really great!!

Please let me know if you have other methods to achieve this effect.

visit http://www.hipmunk.com for the maximizing minimizing effect
and  http://css3playground.com/flip-card.php for the flipping thing.

Comment: Uhm, are you using CSS transitions to this ?

Comment: nothing in your code should be causing any queueing. Most likely it's unrelated to the code you have shown us.

Comment: I don't see how this could produce any animated effects. You should use the `.animate()` function with specific styles, or use jQuery UI to animate CSS classes

Comment: Can't fid the issue you mentioned with your code.
http://jsfiddle.net/bugJV/

Comment: Can you post the css here

Comment: @ChamikaSandamal The css is way too big.. the code works perfectly in mozilla firefox but in other browsers, the div, shifts its place to a new place then maximizes/minimizes itself..

Comment: @adeneo : Yes.. I am using css- transitions.. I have added the css too.. please find it in description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the divs to move to a new position and maximize or increase the size (looks like queuing, but it is not! )is because, I have animated the div completely by giving

```
-o-transition: 0.5s;
-ms-transition: 0.5s;
-moz-transition: 0.5s;
-webkit-transition: 0.5s;
transition: 0.5s;
```

instead, you just have to animate the top and left alone.

```
-o-transition: left 0.3s ease-out,top 0.3s ease-out;
-ms-transition: left 0.3s ease-out,top 0.3s ease-out;
-moz-transition: left 0.3s ease-out,top 0.3s ease-out;
-webkit-transition: left 0.3s ease-out,top 0.3s ease-out;
transition: left 0.3s ease-out,top 0.3s ease-out;
```